# What parts on a printed circuit board can make unintended sound?

Tags: pcb, sound

To rephrase it: Since vibrations are responsible for soundwaves, what parts are most prone to such vibrations? Root causes are probably electrical oscillations between capacitors and inductors in the kHz region - are there different causes?

Comment: Vibrating transformers, high frequency oscillators, piezoelectric effects in ceramic capacitors. These tend to be the most common.

Comment: Faulty old power transistor or dry joints can make interesting thunderstorms in your loudspeakers....

Comment: Don't forget elongation/contraction of ferromagnetic inductor cores under varying mag flux

Comment: @duskwuff yes, it solved my question. An even better answer is given [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/126502/how-can-purely-electrical-circuits-emit-sound?rq=1). I thought I did search, but if I did it was not well enough ...

Answer (score 0):

There can often be issues with [coil whine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coil_noise) from inductors or transformers - I recently had this issue with a computer PSU. If the magnetic field generated by the component is oscillating (ac current) it can create a mechanical vibration in the components resulting in sound being generated.